# ionic4/angular7 sending an image thumbnail through WhatsApp

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

running into a pickle here. I am using Ionic 4 and Angular 7. I have an app that when you click on the `share` button the action sheet slides up and asks you which channel you want to share through. I select `WhatsApp` choose the person and then one of three things happen.

1. in the console where I have the `.catch()` statement it just shows the link to the image I tried
2. says 'URL_NOT_SUPPORTED'
3. the url's end point is sent.

the docs say this about the param:

> URL(s) to file(s) or image(s), local path(s) to file(s) or image(s), or base64 data of an image. Only the first file/image will be used on Windows Phone.

I have tried to host the image on github and link to there, doesn't work, and I have tried copying the absolute and relative path but doesn't work. The only thing I haven't tried is the Base64 option but that seems unnecessary.

I am trying to do this through an Android phone currently, here is the code if you're interested.

```js
    this.socialSharing
      .share(
        'title goes here',
        'sent from app',
        '/Users/c.francia/Desktop/<folder>/<folder>/application/app/src/assets/theImage.jpg', //<-I've also try hosting and linking here
        'http://www.dicus.es',
      )
      .then()
      .catch(e => console.log('e -->', e));
  }
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `/Users/` isn't a valid URL in your app. That path seems more like a path on your computer. Have you already looked at https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#5-web-share-api?

Comment: @Zun it says that I can also do local paths. yes, I have been going over it

Comment: so if you disconnect your phone from your PC, how is your phone supposed to know anything about the path on your PC. And what if you turn off your PC? As you can see this path doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "The local filesystem" refers to the filesystem where the app is installed (so the iOS/Android/Windows phone). Not your PC.

Comment: but even if I have the image stored in the project itself it still doesn't load it. so not referencing through the User path, this is in my `assets` file where images are loaded for the app. Surely it would be able to grab ahold of that image

Comment: I highly recommend you make sure you only ask 1 question, or present 1 problem at the time. Right now you apparently have a different issue.

Comment: alright I'll make another one.